# Pointers in R (pointr package): How do I know how much memory pointers are taking up?

Tags: r, pointers, memory

I am using this package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pointr/index.html to create pointers as an alternative to declaring new variables, which would take up more memory.

However, I have not figured out how much memory these pointers are taking up. When a pointer is given as an argument to object.size() function, the object.size() function returns (understandably) the size of the variable at which the pointer is pointing at:

```
> library(pointr)
> myvar <- 3
> ptr("mypointer", "myvar")
> myvar
[1] 3
> mypointer
[1] 3
> object.size(mypointer)
56 bytes
> object.size(myvar)
56 bytes
```

Is there a way to see the size of the pointer itself?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the way I understand it, pointers are just a way to say "this object is stored here in the memory". Therefore, you can ask for the size of an object, but I don't think it makes sense to ask the size of the pointer itself.

Comment: @bretauv This would be the case in, say, C. However, there are no pointers in the same sense in R. "Pointr" package is using active bindings to mimic the behavior of pointers. And now I would like to know how extensively I can use these "pointers" i.e. "active bindings" in order to keep memory usage reasonable.